# Como colocar um vídeo para abrir em fullscreen automaticamente em uma página HTML?

Tags: vídeo, html5-video, fullscreen, reprodutor-de-video

Aparentemente para que um vídeo fique em *fullscreen* é preciso que haja a interação com usuário. A maioria dos *players*, incluindo o nativo HTML5 tem botão '*fullscreen*'.

Estou construindo uma plataforma interativa *offline*, e preciso que ao clicar num botão (*teaser*), automaticamente abra um player reproduzindo um vídeo em *fullscreen* e que ao término permaneça na  ou volte para a tela que estava:

[image: Selecione o modo de visualização]

Pensei nessas duas soluções, que estão dentro da minha atual capacidade de programação:

1) Criar outra página HTML com o seguintes códigos:

```
<body class="fadein">

  <video id=video autobuffer autoplay="true">
  <source src="media_v/video.mp4">
  <object type="video/mp4" data="media_v/video.mp4" width="1366" 
height="768">
  </object>
  </video>

<script>
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

function myHandler(e) {
    window.location.href = "menu_option.html";    
}
</script>
```

Acontece que nesse modo ele não toma toda a tela, mesmo com as medidas tendo a resolução nativa da tela 1366x768, ele deixa uma bordinha e não consigo por o objeto em tela toda sem que o usuário clique no botão *fullscreen*, nem mesmo usando:

```
<script>
  var elem = document.getElementById("video");
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
</script>
```

ou

```
video id=video autobuffer autoplay="true" fullscreen="true"
```

Existe "fullscreen='true'"?

2) A outra forma que pensei foi que ao clicar no 'botão' já abra um vídeo 'como sobreposição ao conteúdo' em modo *fullscreen*, como o player do Facebook, mas nesse caso acho que não sei nem por onde começar, por isso cá estou.

Comment: Vídeos em fullscreen automáticos são impraticáveis, uma vez que para abrirmos o modo **tela cheia** sempre precisamos da autorização do usuário.

Comment: Estou ciente dessa imposição, mas como contornar isso? Por exemplo coloquei o tamanho do vídeo com o mesmo da resolução nativa da tela que irá receber essa interface, que irá funcionar em fullscreen no modo "kiosk" do Chrome. O que fazer? Já que ainda fica uma borda no objeto?

Comment: tem como abrir 100% porém os controles não aparecem. vaja http://kithomepage.com/sos/Video.htm

Comment: Obrigado, irei verificar!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar o style do vídeo:

```
 <video id=video autobuffer autoplay="true">
  <source src="media_v/video.mp4">
  <object type="video/mp4" data="media_v/video.mp4"  min-width: 100% min-height: 100%">
  </object>
  </video>
```

Comment: Opa, foi mal... tava me referindo as propriedades do object type. Não sei porque escrevi "Style"!!! Sorry :(

Comment: Tudo bem! Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, mas adicionar  "min-width: 100% min-height: 100%" não muda nada no meu código, e na verdade seria " min-width= 100% min-height= 100%", só consigo usar o redimensionamento através do CSS em  video { width:100%; height:100%} fora disso ele não aceita.

Answer (score 1):

O HTML 5 não fornece nenhuma maneira de fazer um vídeo em tela cheia, mas a especificação em Fullscreen paralela fornece o método requestFullScreen que permite que elementos arbitrários (incluindo elementos ) sejam criados em tela cheia.

Possui suporte experimental em [vários navegadores.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen)

Ou seja, você pode usar esta função arbitraria mas deve ficar atento, pois ela não é universalmente aceitar.

A implementação da mesma se faz assim:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector("#polina button");

if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion)').matches) {
    vid.removeAttribute("autoplay");
    vid.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
}

function vidFade() {
  vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}

vid.addEventListener('ended', function()
{
// only functional if "loop" is removed 
vid.pause();
// to capture IE10
vidFade();
}); 


pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000; 
}
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
.stopfade { 
   opacity: .5;
}

#polina { 
  font-family: Agenda-Light, Agenda Light, Agenda, Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  font-weight:100; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 33%;
  margin:2rem;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
}
#polina button { 
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  padding: .4rem;
  border: none; 
  margin: 1rem auto; 
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px; 
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s background;
}
#polina button:hover { 
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: .5rem;
  transition: .6s background; 
}
a:hover{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
  div{width:70%;} 
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
  html { background: url(https://thenewcode.com/assets/images/polina.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; }
  #bgvid { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="polina">
<h1>Polina</h1>
<p>filmed by Alexander Wagner 2011
<p><a href="http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video">original article</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
<p>Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nisl.</p>
<button>Pause</button>
</div>
```

Mais dados: https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/video.html#video

Comment: Rapaz, que coisa linda esse código, muito interessante mesmo, embora eu tenha implementado através de CSS, vou salvar esse código aqui! Obrigado! E perdão pela demora.

Comment: Tudo bem, espero que seja util.

Comment: @dib espero que tenha sido util, se foi e puder marcar como certo.